# Why object instantly jumps when I use while loop, but moves smooth when done in update

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, while-loop

Explanation:
Hello, I am a very beginner programmer just starting with C#. I got stuck on a thing where I want to move a cube in Unity 3D from point A to point B. I would like it to stop, when it reaches certain point.

Issue:
My issue is, that when I move the object in update, it moves fine. When I add conditions and add it to a while loop it just jumps (the commented section). I can not find any tutorial or info on what I am doing wrong. I watched many tutorials covering loops and such, but it did not help me.

Desired result:
Smooth movement of the cube between point A and B in while loop

Any help is appreciated
Thank you

Tomas

```
 using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class PujdeTo : MonoBehaviour {

        public bool moveBox = true;
        public float objectSpeed = 1;

        void Start () {

        }

        void Update ()
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.left * (objectSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
        }
        void FixedUpdate()
        {
            //while (moveBox == true)
            //{
            //    transform.Translate(Vector3.left * (objectSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
            //    //transform.localPosition += Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * speed;
            //    if (transform.localPosition.x <= -10)
            //    {
            //        moveBox = false;
            //    }
            //}
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Were you using both `Update()` and `FixedUpdate()` at the same time? On a side note, `moveBox == true` in a condition is redundant since `moveBox` is already a boolean, use just `while (moveBox)` instead. Actually, you can get rid of the entire `while` loop, and you don't need the `moveBox` variable.

Comment: This code is part of a bigger thing, that is why the bool stuff is there. Answer from Groo helped me to figure it out. Thank you anyway for the quick answer.

Comment: When I said you didn't need the `moveBox` variable at all I meant exactly what Groo's answers suggest: you don't need to check `moveBox` to stop the object from moving, you can simply check its position. Always try simplifying your logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the `Update()` method as the loop *body*. Unity is calling this method once for each frame.

Since the actual drawing is being done in a separate method, the only thing that Unity is concerned with is what the values are **after the method is finished**.

In other words, you probably want something like:

```
void Update () 
{
    if (!moveBox)
    {
        return; 
    }

    transform.Translate(Vector3.left * (objectSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
    if (transform.localPosition.x <= -10)
    {
        moveBox = false;
    }
}
```

Or simply:

```
void Update () 
{
    if (transform.localPosition.x > -10)
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.left * (objectSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to add a comment but it says I should not just use it to thank you. How else can I thank you than? This was very helpful to me, and works like a charm. Now I better understand how the code flows between the lines. Did not know this before. Thank you!